# Excel Formatting: Tracking Distance (if statements, random number, sum)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hey there Stackoverflow users!

So I'm trying to track mileage for the distance of drives to different addresses in different cities. I made an example table of what I'm trying to accomplish. Let's say we started with 100 km and drove to somewhere in CITY2 which let's say takes between 8-25 km (there and back) so we get "KM" 10. This gets added to our start and we get 110. Now the next "start" is 110 and we drive to CITY1 which is 26-45 km for example. Let's say that was 30, which gets added to the "Start" and you get "End" which goes down. And so on and so on.

Now, I could do the basic C2 =B2+D2 and B3 =C2, but I'm not 100% sure how to check if a cell contains a certain text (in this case, "CITY#"). And if it does contain a certain CITY#, then I need to have "KM" produce a random number between a range of numbers to then get added to "Start" to result in "End."

Also here are the ranges
CITY1 (26-45),
CITY2 (8-25),
CITY3 (45-60),
CITY4 (0). The E column was just a test for search.

Any help would be appreciated!

*EDIT: So I have =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CITY2",A2)),RANDBETWEEN(26,45)) but is there a more efficient way to check the other CITY# or do I just make one long SEARCH thing?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should at least get you started, with the caveat that all your addresses must end in *"comma-space-CityName"*, and there are no other instances of *"comma-space"*.

Use `RIGHT` and `FIND` to extract the city name, and then `VLOOKUP` the name against a table with city name and range boundaries. Finally generate and random number between the range using `RANDBETWEEN`.

Formula in `D2`:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(", ", A2)-1),$F$1:$H$5,2,0),VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(", ", A2)-1),$F$1:$H$5,3,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you! I just did `"=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CITY2",A2)),RANDBETWEEN(26,45),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CITY1",A2)),RANDBETWEEN(8,25),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CITY3",A2)),RANDBETWEEN(46,60),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CITY4",A2)),0))))"` which is quite long haha but it makes sense to me. I'll look into your method though

Comment: Oh I just realized I didn't want "CITY4" to be its own city. I meant it to be any city other than 1,2 or 3. Thanks for all your help. I'll find out how to do this now.

Comment: One option then would be to wrap the entire function in `IFERROR`. So something like `IFERROR(x, 0)`, where x is the function. Or just replace the 4th `IF(ISNUMBER...` in your function with 0.

Comment: Yeah that worked! Although the problem with this `RANDBETWEEN` is that every time I edit a cell, all the numbers change. I'd rather keep them as their first random number

Comment: Multiple ways to do this - [here's one idea](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2007/how-do-i-freeze-the-numbers-given-by-randbetween/6e488bdc-fafd-4e1c-bab2-578567533da4), and there are others out there.